# Unable to debug in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, com

I am receiving an intermittent (but extremely frequent) error when attempting to debug my web app using Visual Studio 2012 and IE 11 via f5.

The error is a message box: "Unable to start program 'http://localhost:36422/default.aspx'.   Access is denied."

Internet explorer opens, but no page is loaded.

If I retry enough times, it will eventually succeed, my app loads and I can debug.

I have noticed via task manager that when the error occurs, the internet explorer process is hanging around after I close it.  The number of ie processes continues to build up until I have to kill them.

I am getting a large number of errors in my system event log which may be related (although an entry is not generated every time the error occurs):

The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{0C0A3666-30C9-11D0-8F20-00805F2CD064}
 and APPID 
{9209B1A6-964A-11D0-9372-00A0C9034910}
 to the user *my user name* SID (S-1-5-21-1364137996-2577644926-3768900005-1179) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

A google search of the guid indicates that the application in question is Machine Debug Manager.

I have tried adding the interactive user to the access permissions for Machine Debug Manager using dcomcnfg and rebooting my pc to no effect.

Comment: are you running VS as administrator?

Comment: I've tried doing a Run As Administrator when launching VS to ensure that I am and still receive the error intermittently

Comment: try changing port number

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, changing the port number did not work unfortunately

Comment: The problem seems to have gone away - at least for now